# Cleaner way to write this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

This is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE blah blah...
AND users.who = '1'

AND users.seeking = '2' 
OR users.seeking = '5' 
OR users.seeking = '8' 
OR users.seeking = '9' 
OR users.seeking = '11' 
OR users.seeking = '13' 
OR users.seeking = '14' 
OR users.seeking = '15' 

AND users.account_status = '1';
```

As you can see the seeking field can have multiple values. Rather than writing so many OR's is there a prettier way to specify all the acceptable values for that field in order to be returned by my select statement?

Comment: As your query stands, it will return rows where `users.seeking = '9'` even if `users.who` is **not** `'1'` (and similarly `users.account_status` may not be `'1'`). The answers using `in` will change that (which I presume is a good thing, but I just thought I'd mention it).

Comment: Off-topic, but why are all your numbers in quotes? E.g., why are the strings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE blah blah...
AND users.who = '1'

AND users.seeking IN('2','5','8','9','11','13','14','15') 
AND users.account_status = '1';
```

Comment: Separately, probably worth pointing out that this changes the query -- but almost certainly in a way that fixes a bug. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yea that was a bug, thanks for pointing it out.